# mvc: how to disable cache busting in debug mode

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, caching

in MVC my scripts are getting cache busted in DEBUG mode

[check here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7DT9g.png) (sorry cant post image as I don't have enough reputations)

I want to disable cache-busting, I tried below

```
BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = false;
```

and in web.config

```
<location path="Scripts">
    <system.webServer>
      <staticContent>
        <clientCache cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="365.00:00:00" cacheControlCustom="public" />
      </staticContent>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
```

but still the scripts are getting cache-busted, where else can I check to disable cache-busting... IIS?

Comment: Why would you want this in the first place? Nothing in development should be cached, since that would obviously make it very difficult to make changes in development, which is pretty much why this is just how it works.

Comment: I am talking about the scripts folder `path="Scripts"`, they are not going to change... plus its the client who is doing testing in debug mode, and its making things slow for them.. hence the requirement